# Who is this character?

Tags: merchandise

Can somebody please tell me what is the name of this character?

I am trying to find this character's name. I have tried to google it and went through a couple of anime lists, but it just doesn't ring a bell.

[image]

Comment: @Memor-X Doesn't this fall under the merchandise-identification exception? Either way, it's a figure of Near from Death Note.

Comment: @senshin ahh yes your're right, my mistake

Comment: Voted to reopen and upvoted for actually having a picture instead of just describing it. Also that is a really good Near figure. Who made it? How much is it? And who can I give my hard-earned money to?

Answer (score 4):

As noted in the comments by Senshin, this is a figure of *Death Note's* [Near](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Near).

[image]